# Avoid duplicate retrofit callback

Tags: android, retrofit

I implemented Facebook login using Retrofit in my latest Android application. In SplashActivity and LoginActivity, I want to make my POST request:

```
FacebookLoginInfo facebookLoginInfo = new FacebookLoginInfo(token);
Call<User> call = ApiManager.getService().authenticateFacebookUser(facebookLoginInfo);
call.enqueue(userCallback);
```

FacebookLoginInfo is a simple POJO with the Facebook access token. ApiManager is singleton class for my service.

My issue is that userCallback is duplicate in SplashActivity and LoginActivity. Is there a best practise to define this callback only once ?

---

Definition of the user callback:

```
private Callback<User> mUserCallback = new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        dismissProgressDialog();

        int statusCode = response.code();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            User user = response.body();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "user: " + user.toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Global.EXTRA_USER, user);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (statusCode == 400) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_token_required), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (statusCode == 403) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_invalid_token), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        t.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_call_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  create a class called UserCallback that implements Callback and use it where you want.

in your case:

```
public class UserCallback implements Callback<EventResponseList> {
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        dismissProgressDialog();

        int statusCode = response.code();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            User user = response.body();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "user: " + user.toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Global.EXTRA_USER, user);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (statusCode == 400) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_token_required), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (statusCode == 403) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_invalid_token), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        t.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_call_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and when you want to use it:

```
FacebookLoginInfo facebookLoginInfo = new FacebookLoginInfo(token);
Call<User> call = ApiManager.getService().authenticateFacebookUser(facebookLoginInfo);
call.enqueue(new UserCallback());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to make my asynchronous call with call.enqueue(new Callback<>() {}). My question is more, what is the best practise if I want to use the same callback in two different activity ?

Comment: I think you should create a class called UserCallback that implements Callback and use it where you want.

Comment: I worked on an open source app and that how we solve this problem 
please take a look
https://github.com/fossasia/open-event-android/blob/master/app%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Ffossasia%2Fopenevent%2Fapi%2Fprocessor%2FEventListResponseProcessor.java